# Nested JSON expressions are converted to strings after a union

Tags: sql-server, json

The following query properly nests ContactAddress as an array under the outer JSON object:

```
select 
    Json_Query(IsNull((
        select [Name], [Id], 
            (IsNull((
                select [Address1], [ContactId] from [ContactAddress] where [ContactAddress].[ContactId] = [Contact].[Id] for json path, include_null_values
            ), Json_Query('[]'))) [Address] 
            from [Contact] 
            where [Contact].[Name] like N'Tes%' 
        for json path, include_null_values
    ), Json_Query('[]'))) data for json path
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "Name": "Test 'em Joe",
                "Id": 145,
                "Address": [
                    {
                        "Address1": "1234 Testing Ln",
                        "ContactId": 145
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But if I wish to use a union, SQL Server requires that the union be nested like this:

```
select 
    Json_Query(IsNull((
        select * from (
            select [Name], [Id], 
                (IsNull((
                    select [Address1], [ContactId] from [ContactAddress] where [ContactAddress].[ContactId] = [Contact].[Id] for json path, include_null_values
                ), Json_Query('[]'))) [Address] 
                from [Contact] 
                where [Contact].[Name] like N'Tes%' 
            union all 
            select [Name], [Id], 
                (IsNull((
                    select [Address1], [ContactId] from [ContactAddress] where [ContactAddress].[ContactId] = [Contact].[Id] for json path, include_null_values
                ), Json_Query('[]'))) [Address] 
                from [Contact]
                join [ContactAddress] on [ContactAddress].[ContactId] = [Contact].[Id] 
                    and [ContactAddress].[Address1] like N'Tes%' 
            ) _
        for json path, include_null_values
    ), Json_Query('[]'))) data for json path
```

But the union seems to cause the metadata about the nested JSON to be lost.  Here is the result:

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "Name": "Test 'em Joe",
                "Id": 145,
                "Address": "[{\"Address1\":\"1234 Testing Ln\",\"ContactId\":145}]"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put `JSON_QUERY` on the outer part of a `UNION` otherwise the compiler doesn't understand that it's already valid JSON. You also need `JSON_QUERY` on the outside of an `ISNULL` rather than the inside.

Having said that, you can actually optimize your existing query significantly, by combining the two unions.

You should also use short table aliases, and don't quote names with `[]` unless absolutely necessary, because it's really hard to read otherwise.

```sql
SELECT 
  ISNULL((
      SELECT
        c.Name,
        c.Id,
        JSON_QUERY(
          ISNULL((
            SELECT
              ca.Address1,
              ca.ContactId
            FROM ContactAddress ca
            WHERE ca.ContactId = c.Id
            for json path, include_null_values
          ),
          '[]')
        ) Address
      FROM Contact c
      WHERE c.Name LIKE N'Tes%'
         OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM ContactAddress ca
          WHERE ca.ContactId = c.Id
            AND ca.Address1 LIKE N'Tes%'
      )
      for json path, include_null_values
    ),
    '{"data":[]}'
 );
```

Another option, which might be more efficient as it only queries `ContactAddress` once

```sql
SELECT 
  ISNULL((
      SELECT
        c.Name,
        c.Id,
        JSON_QUERY(ISNULL(a.Address, '[]')) Address
      FROM Contact c
      OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT
            ca.Address1,
            ca.ContactId
          FROM ContactAddress ca
          WHERE ca.ContactId = c.Id
          for json path, include_null_values
      ) a(Address)
      WHERE c.Name LIKE N'Tes%'
         OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM OPENJSON(a.Address)
            WITH (Address1 nvarchar(100)) j
          WHERE j.Address1 LIKE N'Tes%'
      )
      for json path, include_null_values
    ),
    '{"data":[]}'
 );
```

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface, this SQL is auto-generated.  I too hate unnecessary quoted identifiers when unnecessary.  The union is generated because OR is only an option within a single table and this code generator wants to create results for all possible search conditions across join conditions would would be quite difficult when intermixed with other filters.  I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Though this should perhaps be considered a bug in the compiler inference in SQL Server, this can be worked-around by using `Json_Query()` explicit in the outer query of the nesting.  Here is an example:

```
select 
    Json_Query(IsNull((
        select Name, Id, Json_Query(Address) Address from (
            select [Name], [Id], 
                (IsNull((
                    select [Address1], [ContactId] from [ContactAddress] where [ContactAddress].[ContactId] = [Contact].[Id] for json path, include_null_values
                ), Json_Query('[]'))) [Address] 
                from [Contact] 
                where [Contact].[Name] like N'Tes%' 
            union all 
            select [Name], [Id], 
                (IsNull((
                    select [Address1], [ContactId] from [ContactAddress] where [ContactAddress].[ContactId] = [Contact].[Id] for json path, include_null_values
                ), Json_Query('[]'))) [Address] 
                from [Contact]
                join [ContactAddress] on [ContactAddress].[ContactId] = [Contact].[Id] 
                    and [ContactAddress].[Address1] like N'Tes%' 
            ) _
        for json path, include_null_values
    ), Json_Query('[]'))) data for json path
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "Name": "Test 'em Joe",
                "Id": 145,
                "Address": [
                    {
                        "Address1": "1234 Testing Ln",
                        "ContactId": 145
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```